# WPF Blurry borders

Tags: c#, wpf, render

I've added a progress bar to my workspace in WPF project. I've set BorderBrush color and Background color. In editor view is everything alright. But when I try to run my app the borders are getting blurry and I really don't know why.

Here is code of StackPanel that contains the progress bar:

```
<StackPanel Width="570px" Height="70px" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0">
    <ProgressBar Name="DownloadProgress" Width="570px" Height="30px"
                 Opacity="1" Background="#434551" BorderBrush="#2C2C38" BorderThickness="1"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <Label Name="Status" Content="Updated to version 0.0.1567" Foreground="#6B7E7F"
                   Margin="0,5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    </Label>
</StackPanel>
```

Here is how it looks in editor:

[image]

And here is how it looks after run:

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All you have to do is set [SnapsToDevicePixels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels(v=vs.110).aspx)  to `true` in stackpanel.

```
  <StackPanel Width="570px" Height="70px" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="10,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
```

Also look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908(v=vs.90).aspx)